# Solve diophantine using modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Find all pairs of positive integers $(m, n)$ that satisfy,

$mn + 3m - 8n = 59$

Using Modular arithmetic.

Okay, this is a diophantine equation, where can I begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

I would begin by factoring as follows
$$(m-8)(n+3)=59-24=35 = 1\cdot 5\cdot7$$

Now can you think of the possibilities for $m-8, n+3$?  Do not forget $m, n > 0$

---

*P.S. Modular arithmetic seems really unnecessary here, though it wouldn't be hard to contrive its use to solve.*

Comment: I know this factoring method, I wanted to try modulus (+1) anyway.

Comment: I have found modular arithmetic more useful when you want to prove no solutions exist, or rule out families of solutions. To find a finite number of them, not so much - but then again there are not many universal rules when it comes to diophantine equations.

Answer (score 2):

We have $m=\dfrac{8n+59}{n+3}$

Let integer $d$ divides both $n+3,8n+59\implies d$ must divide $8n+59-8(n+3)=35$

Now for integer $m,n+3$ must divide $35\implies n+3$ must be $\in\{\pm1,\pm5,\pm7,\pm35\}$

But $n>0\iff n+3>3\implies n+3$ must be $\in\{5,7,35\}$

Test with each of the three possible values

Answer (score 0):

$(m,n) \in \lbrace(9,32),(13,4),(15,2)\rbrace$

$$\begin{align}
mn + 3m - 8n &= 59 \\
mn+3m-8n-24&=59-24=35 \\
(m-8)(n+3)&=35=d_1 d_2 \\
\begin{cases}
m-8=d_1 \\
n+3=d_2 \\ 
\end{cases} \implies 
&\begin{cases}
m=d_1+8 \\
n=d_2-3
\end{cases} \\
\text{such that} \quad (d_1,d_2) &\in \lbrace (1,35),(5,7),(7,5),\color{red}{(35,1)} \rbrace \\
(35,1) \implies n<0 
\end{align}$$